# SCRAPY : Unable to __scrape__ page using FormRequest.from_response()

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'dnn_ctr410_MemberSearch_txtMembershipNumber': '61915'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )
    
    def after_login(self, response):
        print(response)
        return response
```

Since the form has multiple fields that are getting filled with session related data, I'm using from_response and adding only value against the membership number using the id of the input.

however this isn't working and i get an error stating `Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'HtmlResponse'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return correct type from `after_login` method. list of types mentioned in the exception message.
So you after_login method should look something like:

```py
def after_login(self, response):
    print(response)
    # response.css('') find something using CSS selector
    # response.xpath('') or using xpath
    yield {'some_field_name': 'field value'}
```

In your example, you return `response` which has `HtmlResponse` type, but scrapy expected other types, like `request, item, or None`

Comment: in `after_login` method, i did `organization = response.css('#dnn_ctr410_MemberSearch_grdMembers_ctl00_ctl04_lblOrganizationName::text').get()` to get the organization name after the form is submitted. 

but i get `{'organization': None}` instead of getting the organization name

Comment: also i realized that the response length is zero.